# How do I define the response to a missing claim in NancyFX?

Tags: authentication, claims, nancy

I have a module meant to enable administrators to manage users. Of course, this module requires not only authentication but also a specific claim. I have discovered that, if you are missing the claim in question, you actually get only a blank page as a response to your request. This isn't ideal.

How can I change that?

Module code below (if anyone needs to look)...

```
public class UserModule : NancyModule
{
    public UserModule()
        : base("/users")
    {
        this.RequiresAnyClaim(new[] { "evil-dictator" });

        Get["/"] = _ =>
        {
            ViewBag.UserName = Context.CurrentUser.UserName;
            return Negotiate.WithView("Index");
        };

        // Generate an invitation for a pre-approved user
        Get["/invite"] = _ =>
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [`After` hook](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-before-and-after-module-hooks#intercepting-the-request-after-the-route-was-invoked) to alter the response in case the claim is missing. Note that the response you get when you do not have the required claim has HTTP status code `403 Forbidden`. Check for that in the `After` hook and alter the response as needed.

E.g. the following will redirect to the root - `"/"` - of the application, when the user does have the evil dictator claim:

```
public class UserModule : NancyModule
{
    public UserModule()
        : base("/users")
    {
        After += context =>
        {
            if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
              ctx.Response = this.Response.AsRedirect("/");
        }

        this.RequiresAnyClaim(new[] { "evil-dictator" });

        Get["/"] = _ =>
        {
            ViewBag.UserName = Context.CurrentUser.UserName;
            return Negotiate.WithView("Index");
        };

        // Generate an invitation for a pre-approved user
       Get["/invite"] = _ =>
       {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
       };
    }
}
```